# How to extract some sample in R

Tags: r

How do I extract only random numbers(CD) for 'Trt' at time point 1.

```
ns <- 20
ans <- matrix(rep(0,200),nrow=100)
for(k in 1:100)
{ 
x1=rnorm(ns,0,1)
x2=rnorm(ns,5,5)
x3=rnorm(ns,10,5)
U=c(x1,x2,x3)
simdata=data.frame(CD=U,
                   Time=factor(rep(c(1,2,3),each=ns)),
                   treatment=sample(rep(c('Trt','placebo'),ns/2)))
ans[k,]=table(simdata$treatment)
}
simdata
```

Comment: `subset(simdata, Time == 1, select = "CD")`.

Comment: May be I did not explain myself very well. I need to see the CD,Treatment displaying all the 10 'Trts' in time 1. Thank you

Comment: @user3407190 see my answer, it gives you exactly that

Comment: @user3407190 I noticed that you *unaccepted* my answer. I like to know why. Was there something wrong?

Comment: @Jaap sorry I thought you could accept as many correct answers as possible. In that case I will do the honorable thing. It is only fair that I accept yours instead since you were first to respond.

Comment: @user3407190 It's not possible to accept more than one answer. What you can do when you get several good answers, is giving the other answers an upvote (you need a minimum reputation of 15 before you can do that though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset for both conditions (`treatment` = "Trt" and `Time` = "1") like this:

```
smpl <- simdata[simdata$Time=="1" & simdata$treatment=="Trt",]
```

If you only want the `CD` column:

```
smpl <- simdata$CD[simdata$Time=="1" & simdata$treatment=="Trt",]
```

Comment: A sidenote: it's better to use [`[` instead of `subset`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in multiple ways:

```
simdata$CD[sim_data$Time == 1]
```

or use `subset`:

```
subset(simdata, Time == 1, select = "CD")
```

The former is recommended for use in scripts, the latter works well in interactive mode (R prompt).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want CD for Timepoint "1" and Treatment ="Trt"

```
subset(simdata, Time == 1 & treatment == "Trt", select = "CD")
```

alternatively for the whole data frame

```
subset(simdata, Time == 1 & treatment == "Trt")
```